# StackWalk of other process in delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, debugging, readprocessmemory

Do you know how to read another process stack in delphi ??

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

You can enumerate threads with [Toolhelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686837%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions; get the context with [`GetThreadContext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679362%28VS.85%29.aspx); and read the stack memory (i.e. using ESP from the context) with [`ReadProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28VS.85%29.aspx). The stack grows downwards in memory, so reading memory locations after ESP is going down the stack.

Comment: And use dbghelp api's to get names from the symbols could be the next step.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the "TThreadSampler.MakeStackDump" procedure of the following unit of my sampling profiler: http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/source/browse/trunk/Sampling/mcThreadSampler.pas

This function can read from the same thread, or same process or different process (each with it's own optimized function).

Btw: my Sampling Profiler reads Delphi debug symbols (.map, .jdbg, etc) because there is still no good Delphi to Pdb debug symbol converter (so you can view the stack of a Delphi program in Windows debugger or Process Explorer, Visual Studio etc). You can also use my sampling profiler for view the current stack of any process! 
http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/wiki/AsmProfilerSamplingMode